# Object Keys Filtering

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can I pass object keys into an array that are true. So that I can use this array for filtering?
Example Object:

```
let results = [
      {name: marc, isAlumnus: true, isScholar: true, isTrustee: false},
      {name: franz, isAlumnus: false, isScholar: true, isTrustee: false},
      {name: Hugo, isAlumnus: true, isScholar: true, isTrustee: false},
    ]
```

And the attempt of a function!

```
getActiveStatusGroups (results) {
            let res = [];
            res = results.map((item) => {
                if (item) {
                    res.push('isScholar');
                }
            });
          return res;
        },

let statusArray = getActiveStatusGroup(this.results)
```

Comment: What do you want in `statusArray` as a result? For instance, that first object in the array has both `isAlumnus` and `isScholar` with `true`, should that be two entries in the result, or...?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: No once the value is true it should be entered into the array. Not more than once

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of the property names from `Object.keys`, or an array of `[name, value]` arrays from `Object.entries`, depending on what you want to do.

It's kind of hard to tell what output you want as a result, but for instance, this returns an array of arrays, where the inner arrays are the names of the properties for which the value was truthy:

```
getActiveStatusGroups(results) {
    return results.map(entry =>
        Object.keys(entry).filter(key => entry[key])
    );
}
```

Live Example:

```js
let results = [
    {isAlumnus: true, isScholar: true, isTrustee: false},
    {isAlumnus: false, isScholar: true, isTrustee: false},
    {isAlumnus: true, isScholar: true, isTrustee: false},
];

function getActiveStatusGroups(results) {
    return results.map(entry =>
        Object.keys(entry).filter(key => entry[key])
    );
}

console.log(getActiveStatusGroups(results));
```

Comment: How can I filter by the values  But not consider the name? Ich I have adapted the object again! Thanks for the help

Comment: @H.Solo - "first" is a tricky concept with JavaScript object properties. :-) Two objects with the same set of properties (both names and values) can have "different" first properties depending on how they're created. So your best bet is to use names explicitly. For instance, to ignore `isTrustee`, update the `.filter` call above to `.filter(key => key !== "isTrustee" && entry[key])`.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering is pretty simple in JavaScript

The methods name is right there in your title, yet you failed to recognize it. Use `filter` instead of `map`. The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Here's your code

```js
let results = [
      {name: marc, isAlumnus: true, isScholar: true, isTrustee: false},
      {name: franz, isAlumnus: false, isScholar: true, isTrustee: false},
      {name: Hugo, isAlumnus: true, isScholar: true, isTrustee: false},
]

getActiveStatusGroups(group) {
  // returns the element if the condition is true
  return results.filter(result => result[group])
}
```

That's it

```js
console.log(getActiveStatusGroups('isAlumnus'))
console.log(getActiveStatusGroups('isScholar'))
console.log(getActiveStatusGroups('isTrustee'))
```